# Different images for IKImageBrowserView and Quick Look

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quicklook, ikimagebrowserview

I'm writing a program that shows images from internet.
I'm using a IKImageBrowserView for it, using NSURLs.
I'd like to show thumbnails in IKImageBrowserView and full res images in Quick Look.
Quick Look is automatically invoked by IKImageBrowserView.
Can i in some way tell to Quick Look to show a different NSURL from which is showed in IKImageBrowserView?

Comment: Take a look at the browser view's delegate messages, if it has any, could be the option there for getting notified before the image is displayed allowing you to swap out the image for a hires alternative.

Comment: no suitable methods in the delegate.. and the class itself only has 
setCanControlQuickLookPanel:

Comment: Hmmm IK stuff looks great on the surface, however I have never successfully managed to use it. I suggest you try an implement this functionality with an NSCollectionView. This is much more frequently used so you will get better community support on any further questions too.